# MLPC Classifier ValueError: hidden_layer_sizes must be > 0, got %s

Tags: python, scikit-learn, deep-learning, neural-network, sklearn-pandas

I am doing a simple variable predicting model and I wanted to try the MLPClassifier NN, but when I run the model:

```
model = MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(50,))
model.fit(train_scaled, y_train)
```

I get the following ValueError:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in line 5
      75 # %%
      76 # MLP model
      78 model = MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(50,))
----> 79 model.fit(train_scaled, y_train)

File c:\Users\XXXXX\.conda\envs\vscodeenv\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\neural_network\_multilayer_perceptron.py:749, in BaseMultilayerPerceptron.fit(self, X, y)
    731 """Fit the model to data matrix X and target(s) y.
    732 
    733 Parameters
   (...)
    745     Returns a trained MLP model.
    746 """
    747 self._validate_params()
--> 749 return self._fit(X, y, incremental=False)

File c:\Users\XXXXX\.conda\envs\vscodeenv\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\neural_network\_multilayer_perceptron.py:437, in BaseMultilayerPerceptron._fit(self, X, y, incremental)
    430     raise ValueError(
    431         "hidden_layer_sizes must be > 0, got %s." % hidden_layer_sizes
    432     )
    433 first_pass = not hasattr(self, "coefs_") or (
    434     not self.warm_start and not incremental
    435 )
...
       0.27279419, 0.09962941, 0.52715763, 0.08205926, 0.3827114 ,
       0.01760811, 0.21987909, 0.22426514, 0.03791925, 0.30050161,
       0.74758455, 0.26717366, 0.29968191, 0.05987187, 0.10532893,
       0.30681938, 0.16610842, 0.19412608, 0.07879216, 0.05996261,
       0.06771538, 0.58000312, 0.10814463]),)
```

Haven't really seen anyone having this online, so I don't know how to solve it. I have tried tuning the number of hidden layers, but still it says "hidden_layer_sizes must be > 0, got %s."

My data is encoded and standardised if it helps.

Comment: can you please post reproducible code? I checked and this code works just fine.